# Replace values in pandas based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to update Status Column from `SCN ISSUED` to `FSCN ISSUED` if Status column is `SCN ISSUED` and `Days` column is greater than 20. I wrote the below line which is highlighting error

```
currenteod = eod.where((eod['Status']=="SCN ISSUED" & eod['Days']>20),eod['Status']="FSCN ISSUED")
```

```
Cannot Assign to Function Call
```

Comment: `eod.where(((eod['Status']=="SCN ISSUED") & (eod['Days']>20)), "FSCN ISSUED")`?

Comment: Also, you can use the `np.where` version: `eod['Status'] = np.where((eod['Status']=="SCN ISSUED") & (eod['Days']>20),"FSCN ISSUED",eod['Status'])`